# Rescue all Errno errors in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I want to grab all the Errno errors like Errno::ENOENT, Errno::EIO, Errno::ENODEV, etc in my program, but I don't want to grab something else - like ArgumentError or RuntimeError.

My current implementation is this:

```
begin
    raise Errno::EIO
rescue StandardError
    raise $! unless $!.class.name.partition(-'::').first == -'Errno'
end
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the names of the constants defined in [`Errno`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Errno.html) using [`Module#constants`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-constants), iterate over them using [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), retrieve the classes stored in those constants using [`Module#const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_get) and use those as the exception filter in the `rescue` clause:

```ruby
begin
  raise Errno::EIO
rescue *Errno.constants(false).map(&Errno.method(:const_get)) => e
  p e
end
# #<Errno::EIO: Input/output error>
```

Comment: Seems like `SystemCallError` is the parent of all `Errno` Exceptions, wouldn't it be easier to rescue that? From Docs: "`SystemCallError` is the base class for all low-level platform-dependent errors. The errors available on the current platform are subclasses of `SystemCallError` and are defined in the `Errno` module."